# .htaccess Apache on cPanel only working in some cases

Tags: apache, zend-framework, .htaccess

I'm using the Zend Framework, so I'm bootstrapping into a file called index.php.  Naturally, I don't want images to be bootstrapped, so I've added a .htaccess file.  Here's what it looks like

```
/application
/library
/public (this is the root of the site)
     /images
     /js
     .htaccess
     index.php
```

This is what's written in my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule !\.(js|ico|gif|jpg|png|mp3|mov|css)$ index.php
```

This is basically saying if it doesn't end in .js / .ico / etc, then send the request to index.php.   It works just fine on my localhost, but when I get up to actually putting it online, it doesn't.  It just routes everything to index.php, regardless of the ending of the request.  When mywebsite.com/images/wizard.gif should just show the picture, it tries to load the images controller, which is not what I want it to do.

What could be going wrong?  I know it's reading the .htaccess.  Is it reading my regex wrong?  Why would one apache server read it wrong, while another reads it correctly?  Any help would be great.

Comment: Try requesting the configuration of your hosting provider with regards to .htaccess and overrides. If they don't allow you to override certain configuration using a .htaccess, that could cause unexpected behavior.
Also, perhaps they don't support rewrites in the way that you do. Do they use the same Apache version as you do?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my .htaccess if you would like to give it a try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.php [NC,L]
```

Basically it checks to make sure the request is not a directory, symlink or a real file, and then sends it to index.php. Otherwise it will provide direct access to the file/directory